# Access httponly cookie from server side (ASP.NET 4.5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, webforms, httponly

I am trying to retrieve an httponly cookie over https from code behind and then set to session variable to retrieve from web form page. The code is on the same domain.

```
HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["CookieName"];
            if (cookie != null)
            {
                string token_value = cookie.Value.ToString();

                Session.Add("TestCookie", token_value);
            }
```

In my web form, I try to retrieve the session variable, but value is null.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var cookie_value = '<%= Session["TestCookie"] %>';
        alert(cookie_value);
    </script>
```

Comment: In your first bit of code, is the cookie set?

Comment: No, keep getting a null value. The cookie is present, but code behind can't see it.

Comment: If I manually create a cookie, I can retrieve the value. The cookie is being passed along as a user is redirected after logging into main application. Redirect takes the user to https://appdomain/myapplication. I need to retrieve the secure cookie and then pass back to a token security service.

Comment: I am having doubts about this approach. If I set the session variable with the token value retrieved from the cookie, then the value will be visible on the client, which defeats the objective of having a secure cookie in the first place. The same rule would apply if using a hidden field. Are there other options to solve this?

Comment: The new approach I'm going to take is to retrieve the secure cookie value from code behind, then call the web api from the code behind. That way I don't expose the cookie value to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Session.Add("TestCookie", cookie);
```

I think you mean to write

```
Session.Add("TestCookie", token_value);
```

Comment: My bad. I had the correct line commented out for testing and forgot to uncomment before posting it here.